# Bind gridview to a list of string

Tags: c#, wpf, gridview, winrt-xaml

Is it possible to bind gridview to a simple list ?
In the data item template I have to specify property name but in case of pure string list there are no any properties

> ```
> <DataTemplate x:Key="AppointmentsGroupedItemTemplate">
>     <StackPanel Width="Auto" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="Auto"  Background="Green">
>         <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto">
>                   <Run Text="{**Binding Name**}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="48"/>
>         </TextBlock>
>     </StackPanel>
> </DataTemplate>
> ```

Comment: `{Binding .}` will bind to entire object, which I believe will be the string object in your case

Comment: @LorentzVedeler: Put it as answer, and I will upvote it. FTR: Just using {Binding} would also work.

Comment: yes, please put it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the items source is string-entries, use the following:

```
    <DataTemplate x:Key="AppointmentsGroupedItemTemplate">
        <StackPanel Width="Auto" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="Auto"  Background="Green">
            <TextBlock Margin="10,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="Auto">
                      <Run Text="{Binding}" Foreground="Black" FontSize="48"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```